# 1 is not '1' == True - basic understanding

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I'm currently having a hard time understanding why the output of

```
1 is not '1' == True
```

is

```
False
```

The thing is when I'm inserting brackets like that:

```
1 is not ('1' == True)
(1 is not '1') == True
```

both return `True`.

I get the second part, because 1, which is True, is not False, which is the result of the comparison of the string "1" and True. Furthermore, the integer 1 is not the string one, which is true and therefore equal to True. But as soon as I do not put any bracket, it returns `False`. Why is that?

Comment: what about `1 is (not '1' == True)`

Comment: `1 is not '1' == True` → `1 is not '1' and '1' == True`. But `(1 is not '1') == True` → `(True) == True`.

Comment: @Moberg, `not` is the indeed the reason this is confusing. Why don't you make it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`is` is used to compare address(reference) while `==` is used t o compare values. Therefore `1 is not '1' == True` is always `False`

As @deceze mentioned, here is the second part:

```
>>> 1 is not ('1' == True)
>>> ('1' == True)
>>> False
>>> 1 is not False
>>> True

>>> (1 is not '1') == True
>>> (1 is not '1')
>>> True
>>> True == True
>>> True
```

Comment: Doesn't explain the opposite results when using parentheses.

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed, that a and b refer to the same address. Please give a resource for that.

Comment: Your example and the observed behaviour are unrelated. This does not answer the question.

Comment: ok, I should delete this answer then

Comment: Yes, because this is a duplicate anyway.

Comment: Hey @coldspeed how is this duplicate, I am not able to see the second part in original post, just like deceze criticize my answer.

Comment: @deceze added the second part